# PHP glob cannot recognize file when change domain with nginx

Tags: php, glob

I have a simple PHP script which creates file with **fopen** and list all those file by **glob**. But every time I change my domain (which still point to this server), the **glob** cannot show the old file before move to domain

Comment: As long as the pattern you give to `glob` as first argument is not affected by domain name, I'd say result of `glob` should not be affected by domain change. If this is the case, you should look for cause somewhere else.

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov the pattern is just "*.*", no special, and I cannot guess somewhere